# Best transportation option from San Jose Del Cabo airport to Cabo San Lucas

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, mexico, taxis, sjd

It appears they have a taxi cartel in that area and all the prices are very high for transportation.

What are the best options for me to get a ride for 2 people from San Jose Del Cabo airport to Cabo San Lucas?

My airbnb host offered to give us a ride for $70. I scoffed at that but now that I see the limited options, it might be the best choice?

**Edit:**
To be more clear on what I'm looking for, my number 1 priority is saving money, and number two priority is timeliness. So I want a good deal, but not if it will turn the 30-40 minute trip into anything greater than 60 minutes.

Comment: `best` to me means a balance between cost and convenience

Comment: @JamesWierzba the problem is that 'balance between cost and convenience ' is subjective. You see it in an airplane, for example - for some people this means business class; for other people premium economy and for many - economy. They all balanced between cost and convenience. You need to be more specific.

Comment: I've updated the question